# last.fm - get amount of artist scrobbles from any profile

Tags: html, parsing, last.fm

I'm aware this isn't a direct code-relevant question, so if this question does not belong here, please accept my apology and point me in the diretion where it's more fitting.

I'm having a project in mind where you type in a last.fm profile name + an artist and the web-page returns the amount of scrobbles the user has with the specific artist.

My first approach would be to use PHP with domdocument and get the  or

where the scrobbles are put in and then parse them to my page - however, looking at the page source I can see the it's input inside a list next to other lists making it seem impossible to parse.

Copy/paste code from last.fm page source:

```
<li class="metadata-item">
  <h2 class="metadata-title">Scrobbles</h2>
  <p class="metadata-display">3,330</p>
</li>
```

So - long story short - what would be the "right" way of getting those scrobbles parsed?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to retrieve data about the number of scrobbles a user has on a specific artist would be using the LastFM API. Fetching from the link:

```
https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=ARTIST_NAME&api_key=API_KEY&format=json&user=USER_NAME
```

This would return a JSON which contains information about the artist but also a stats attribute which contains userplaycount.